# Regex to replace all superscript numbers

Tags: javascript, regex, string, unicode, superscript

I'm struggling to figure out a reasonable solution to this.  I need to replace the following characters: ⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹ using a regex replace. I would think that you would just do this:

```
item = item.replace(/[⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹]/g, '');
```

However, when I try to do that, notepad++ converts symbols 5-9 into regular script numbers.  I realize this probably relates to the encoding format I am using, which I see is set to ANSI.

I've never really understood the difference between the various encoding formats.  But I'm wondering if there is any easy fix for this issue?

Comment: Have you tried setting notepad++ encoding to utf8?

Comment: ^ which you should **always** be using, for everything

Comment: Also, you have to wrap that up `/[⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹]/g` properly, you're missing the starting bracket

Comment: You really have to know the difference between the various character encodings.  It is *essential.*  This should help start your journey. http://kunststube.net/encoding/

Comment: Works just fine if you correct the regex *(and jsFiddle is using UTF8)* -> **https://jsfiddle.net/x010mpdp/**

Comment: You could try ECMAScript 2015 [*unicode escape sequences*](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/es6-unicode-regex), but support might be lacking…

Answer (score 7):

Here is the simple regex for finding all superscript numbers

```
/\p{No}/gu/
```

Breakdown:

- `\p{No}` matches a superscript or subscript digit, or a number that is not a digit [0-9]
- `u modifier`: unicode: Pattern strings are treated as UTF-16. Also causes escape sequences to match unicode characters
- `g modifier`: global. All matches (don't return on first match)

https://regex101.com/r/zA8sJ4/1

Now, most modern browsers still have no built in support for unicode numbers in regex. I would recommend using the `xregexp` library

> XRegExp provides augmented (and extensible) JavaScript regular expressions. You get new modern syntax and flags beyond what browsers support natively. XRegExp is also a regex utility belt with tools to make your client-side grepping and parsing easier, while freeing you from worrying about pesky aspects of JavaScript regexes like cross-browser inconsistencies or manually manipulating lastIndex.

http://xregexp.com/

**HTML Solution**

HTML has a `<sup>` tag for representing superscript text.

> The  tag defines superscript text. Superscript text appears half a character above the normal line, and is sometimes rendered in a smaller font. Superscript text can be used for footnotes, like WWW[1].

If there are superscript numbers, the html markup almost surely has the `sup` tag.

```js
var math = document.getElementById("math");

math.innerHTML = math.innerHTML.replace(/<sup>[\d]?<\/sup>/g, "");
```

```html
<p id="math">4<sup>2</sup>+ 3<sup>2</sup></p>
```

Comment: I don't think that's a valid regex in javascript, the unicode flag is not supported

Comment: @adeneo—Unicode escape sequences (and the u flag) are supported in ECMAScript 2015, however not many browsers seem to have implemented them yet.

Comment: `\p{No}` also matches around [600 other characters](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/list-unicodeset.jsp?a=[:General_Category=Other_Number:]) that aren't superscript numbers.

Comment: @RobG - indeed, didn't know that. I can find it in the spec, but not much about browser support, seems it's not really supported anywhere yet. However, the OP's regex works just fine.

Comment: [You can't parse (X)HTML with regex.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1529630)

Comment: your regex is not supported by javascript.

Comment: Even using `\p{No}` the other number property, in Unicode 11 that matches 807 code points of which the 10 superscript code points are a subset. So, you wouldn't use this to find superscript, it matches too much.

Answer (score 3):

Use UTF-8. If for some reason you can't, a workaround is escaping

```
var rg = new RegExp(
  "[\u2070\u00b9\u00b2\u00b3\u2074\u2075\u2076\u2077\u2078\u2079]",
  "g"
);
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest trying following regex:

```
/[\u2070-\u209f\u00b0-\u00be]+/g
```

Code will look like

```
var re = /[\u2070-\u209f\u00b0-\u00be]+/g; 
var str = '⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹';
var subst = ''; 

var result = str.replace(re, subs);
```

result will contain after successful run:

```
2sometext
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/qD2lB0/1) here