# Split a string after each group of characters

Tags: javascript, string, split

In Javascript, I want to split a string into several segments based on the content.

Each segment is a random set of character, and ends with a unicode superscript character.

An example string would be:

```
this⁵²is¹an³⁶⁻³⁵example²⁴string³¹
```

And the result would be:

```
this⁵²
is¹
an³⁶⁻³⁵
example²⁴
string³¹
```

Each group containing ¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁻ marks the end of each segment.

Comment: You could just use regular regex-y things. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35976910/regex-to-replace-all-superscript-numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`String#match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match), like this:

```
var string = 'this⁵²is¹an³⁶⁻³⁵example²⁴string³¹';

// regex that looks for groups of characters
// containing first a sequence of characters not among '¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁻',
// then a sequence of character among '¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁻'
var regex = /([^¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁻]+[¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁻]+)/g;
var groups = string.match(regex);

console.log(groups);
// prints:
// [ 'this⁵²', 'is¹', 'an³⁶⁻³⁵', 'example²⁴', 'string³¹' ]
```