# find subscript or superscript from string or text

Tags: php, html

how to remove subscript or superscript from below text?

Here [5][6] are in superscript.

The Bhagavad Gita presents a synthesis[5][6] of Hindu ideas about dharma,[5][6][7] theistic bhakti,[8][7] and the yogic paths to moksha.[6] The synthesis presents four paths to spirituality.

is there any way to find it?

Comment: SO is not meant to be a code writing service. Show us what you've tried.  Read the guide on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Can you clarify your question? do you want to find and replace superscript characters with blanks? (you could accidentally remove text that is intended if you create a function like this?). Also, is the php tag necessary?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace superscript and subscript chars from a string Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45163036/replace-superscript-and-subscript-chars-from-a-string-javascript)

Comment: yes i want to find and replace superscript characters with blanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    // regex breakdown
    // \[  matches the left bracket
    // .   any character except line breaks
    // *   0 or more of the preceding character
    // ?   lazy matching
    // \]  matches the right bracket
    $pattern = '/\[.*?\]/';
    $replacement = '';
    $subject = "The Bhagavad Gita presents a synthesis[5][6] of Hindu ideas about dharma,[5][6][7] theistic bhakti,[8][7] and the yogic paths to moksha.[6] The synthesis presents four paths to spirituality.";
    $limit = -1;
    $count = 0;
    $result = preg_replace ($pattern, $replacement, $subject, $limit, $count);
?>
```

Should return

The Bhagavad Gita presents a synthesis of Hindu ideas about dharma, theistic bhakti, and the yogic paths to moksha. The synthesis presents four paths to spirituality.